# Delete div by /{id} json-server

Tags: javascript, rest, crud, http-delete, json-server

I've written a Todo task app, using JSON-Server, to manage the REST routing.

I've uploaded my code here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/json-server-i5hv5

Problem I'm having, is that when I click on a todo task, I want to delete only that DIV by `{id}`, from the database.

However, the delete function only works, if you click on the last div added.  And even then, it deletes all {id}'s in the DB and divs on the page, rather than the single div, I've clicked on.

Struggling to make this work.

I want to only delete the div I click on. And I only want that div to be removed in the DB, by it's allocated `id={id}`.

This is the click function in question:

```
 document.getElementById('id').addEventListener('click', function(event) 
 {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('clicked');

    var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      var id = divs[i].getAttribute('id');
      divs[i].parentElement.removeChild(divs[i]);
      fetchService.deleteTodoTask(id);
    }
  });
```

Any approaches/tips, would be grateful!

Comment: am i supposed to be able to add tasks at that link?

Comment: @lollmbaowtfidgafgtfoohwtbs  for some reason tasks aren't saving in that link, but they do locally, i'll take a look

Comment: well, your code is actually....deleting those divs b/c thats what you are telling it to do. if you dont want to do it for every div, then only do it for the 1 div that you want. you seem to be doing it for them all. remove the for loop.

Comment: @lollmbaowtfidgafgtfoohwtbs - hey, just wondered if you had any ideas with this one. I'm just starting to pick this up again.

Comment: Did you get it? I see you posted a answer below..

Comment: @lollmbaowtfidgafgtfoohwtbs - I did, I managed to work it out. Thank you so much for all you help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working, by changing the way I'm accessing the DOM element on click.  And the below code seems to work well.

I'm them passing the grabbed ID on click, into `fetchService.deleteTodoTask(id)`.
Which is where the delete REST route is being handled:

```
    const list = document.querySelector('.js-todo-list');
    list.addEventListener('click', event => {

   if (event.target.classList.contains('js-delete-todo')) {
     const itemKey = event.target.parentElement.dataset.key;
     const id = itemKey;
     var elem = document.getElementById(id);
     elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
     fetchService.deleteTodoTask(id);
   }
 });


  function deleteTodoTask(id) {
    const options = {
      method: 'DELETE'
    };
    return fetch(`${url}/${id}`, options);
  }
```